# [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 - glibc not found]

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and when I try to execute premake5 tool (http://premake.github.io/download.html) I get the following error and I have not figured out how to solve it yet..

```
premake5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by premake5)
```

I read something on internet that`s caused by this version of Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary version of `premake5` is for a more contemporary OS. The old Ubuntu 12.04 has (g)libc → `libc6` version 2.15 and cannot be used.

`premake5` is also available as source code, `premake-4.4-beta5-src.zip` http://sourceforge.net/projects/premake/files/Premake/4.4/premake-4.4-beta5-src.zip/download ... Or https://github.com/premake/premake-core ...
And you can try if it's possible to build it with Ubuntu 12.04 .

Confirm : `premake5` builds OK with Ubuntu 12.04.5

```
git clone https://github.com/premake/premake-core.git
cd premake-core/
git submodule init
git submodule update
make -f Bootstrap.mak linux
```

Provides `premake-core/bin/release/premake5`